# If statement reiterates when values are same

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this Javascript/jQuery code:

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) { 
    if(!(html == $("#chat-box").html()))
    {           
        $("#chat-box").html(html);
        console.log("a");
    }
}
```

I have this iterating on a for loop 100 times. You would think that at least after the 1st time it would stop iterating unless one of the two values changed (which they don't), but it does not. I do not know why. I tried using `if(htm1 != ...)` and that did not work.

Comment: The interesting thing here would be how the **loop** is written.

Comment: Can you provide the code for the loop as well? As it is, the loop should change it once if they're different, and then check 99 times and do nothing.

Comment: @Pointy Just a basic for loop. Didn't think it was too important. There it is. I also added how I **know** that it keeps using the for loop (console.log).

Comment: @flowstoneknight Exactly! That does not happen though!

Comment: Well, ok, fiddling with `innerHTML` is not the same thing as just assigning a value somewhere. Depending on what's in the "html" variable, the return value - which will be a serialzed version of what the browser thinks the *actual* DOM looks like - may not be exactly the same as the original input.

Comment: @Pointy Right, but shouldn't setting .html() and then reading .html() give the same thing? Is there any way to log that without spamming my console 100 times?

Comment: @ChrisMP no, not necessarily. For example, if "html" contains entity notation for something that doesn't really need it (like `&#32;` for a simple space character) you won't necessarily get that back from the browser.

Comment: It seems to work as expected for me. Maybe it's a browser issue? [Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/jgzn8tus/)

Comment: @flowstoneknight note that we don't know what exactly is in that "html" variable.

Comment: @ChrisMP, did you noticed the `a` printing on the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe using the text() method for your comparison will area the issue:

```
 if(!(html == $("#chat-box").text()))
{           
    $("#chat-box").html(html);
}
```

Reason being is that jQuery processes the text to prevent issues with special characters with html(), where as with text() it returns the raw value.  If it still doesn't work,  console.log() out both method return values and the comparison variable to better visualize.

Comment: That does not work. I will use a counter to display the html once for a clean comparison.

Comment: Post the comparison if you can, will help us troubleshoot, this is something we should be able to sort out quickly.

Comment: I feel silly. Turns out that the html variable returns the same thing, but it uses `'` instead of `$("#chat-box").html()` which uses `"` throughout (i.e `<a href="test.php">` versus `<a href='test.php'>`). Any way to resolve this?

Comment: @ChrisMP You could create a hidden `<div>` somewhere, set its `.html()` to your string and then get it back. That should give you the "browser standard" version of the string.

Comment: Add more specificity to your comparison variables by targeting a unique attribute versus entire string of the html entity.   Using vice in your last comment, if applicable, i would compare the value of the href attributes.

Comment: I have a bunch of each attribute in the actual html. Its a list of names.

Comment: Can you post an example of the html your iterating through and the comparison value?  That would *really* help! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `html` is never being initialized or assigned to. What is it's value? With only the code you provided, it's value is `undefined`. So when you try to do this:

```
$("#chat-box").html(html);
```

What happens is this:

```
$("#chat-box").html(undefined);
```

Which has no effect. But if you were to initialize `html` first, it works:

```
var html = 'stufffff';

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
    if(html !== $("#chat-box").html()) {           
        $("#chat-box").html(html);
        console.log("a");
    }
}
```

Also, you should use `!==` instead of `!=`.

Comment: You're right but the OP simply failed to include the original string.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, but the data is sensitive. I do console.log and I assure you it is exactly the same. The only difference is the use of `'` instead of `"`.

Comment: @ChrisMP Can't you generate some random garbage data that has the same form, for the purposes of sharing so we can test it? Or is the data's form also kind of sensitive?

Comment: It's bad form to ask someone else to debug your code without giving them the full code. Come up with a simple test case that replicates the issue but doesn't involve sensitive data, and give us that. In doing so, you might even figure out the problem for yourself.